# R - ggplot2 - Get histogram of difference between two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a histogram with two overlapping groups.  Here's a possible command from ggplot2 and a pretend output graph.

```
ggplot2(data, aes(x=Variable1, fill=BinaryVariable)) + geom_histogram(position="identity")
```

[image: Overlapping histograms]

So what I have is the frequency or count of each event.  **What I'd like to do instead is to get the difference between the two events in each bin.**  Is this possible?  How?

For example, if we do RED minus BLUE:

- Value at x=2 would be ~ -10
- Value at x=4 would be ~ 40 - 200 = -160
- Value at x=6 would be ~ 190 - 25 = 155
- Value at x=8 would be ~ 10

I'd prefer to do this using ggplot2, but another way would be fine.  My dataframe is set up with items like this toy example (dimensions are actually 25000 rows x 30 columns)  ***EDITED: Here is example data to work with*** [GIST Example](https://gist.github.com/gaiusjaugustus/9c4e465a24881aaaf03d#file-histdifferenceexample)

```
ID   Variable1   BinaryVariable
1     50            T          
2     55            T
3     51            N
..    ..            ..
1000  1001          T
1001  1944          T
1002  1042          N
```

As you can see from my example, I'm interested in a histogram to plot Variable1 (a continuous variable) separately for each BinaryVariable (T or N).  But what I really want is the difference between their frequencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in order to do this we need to make sure that the "bins" we use for the histograms are the same for both levels of your indicator variable. Here's a somewhat naive solution (in base `R`):

```
df = data.frame(y = c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50, mean = 1)),
                x = rep(c(0,1), each = 50))
#full hist
fullhist = hist(df$y, breaks = 20) #specify more breaks than probably necessary
#create histograms for 0 & 1 using breaks from full histogram
zerohist = with(subset(df, x == 0), hist(y, breaks = fullhist$breaks))
oneshist = with(subset(df, x == 1), hist(y, breaks = fullhist$breaks))
#combine the hists
combhist = fullhist
combhist$counts = zerohist$counts - oneshist$counts
plot(combhist)
```

So we specify how many breaks should be used (based on values from the histogram on the full data), and then we compute the differences in the counts at each of those breaks.

**PS** It might be helpful to examine what the non-graphical output of `hist()` is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `ggplot` as requested.
The key idea is to use `ggplot_build` to get the rectangles computed by `stat_histogram.`  From that you can compute the differences in each bin and then create a new plot using `geom_rect.`

#### setup and create a mock dataset with lognormal data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
theme_set(theme_bw())
n1<-500
n2<-500
k1 <- exp(rnorm(n1,8,0.7))
k2 <- exp(rnorm(n2,10,1))
df <- data.table(k=c(k1,k2),label=c(rep('k1',n1),rep('k2',n2)))
```

#### Create the first plot

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=k,group=label,color=label)) + geom_histogram(bins=40) + scale_x_log10()
```

[image: Histogram without showing differences]

#### Get the rectangles using `ggplot_build`

```
p_data <- as.data.table(ggplot_build(p)$data[1])[,.(count,xmin,xmax,group)]
p1_data <- p_data[group==1]
p2_data <- p_data[group==2]
```

#### Join on the x-coordinates to compute the differences. Note that the y-values aren't the counts, but the y-coordinates of the first plot.

```
newplot_data <- merge(p1_data, p2_data, by=c('xmin','xmax'), suffixes = c('.p1','.p2'))
newplot_data <- newplot_data[,diff:=count.p1 - count.p2]
setnames(newplot_data, old=c('y.p1','y.p2'), new=c('k1','k2'))

df2 <- melt(newplot_data,id.vars =c('xmin','xmax'),measure.vars=c('k1','diff','k2'))
```

#### make the final plot

```
ggplot(df2, aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymax=value,ymin=0,group=variable,color=variable)) + geom_rect()
```

[image: Final histogram with bars showing the difference between two distributions.]

Of course the scales and legends still need to be fixed, but that's a different topic.